# Meaning of top, ascent, baseline, descent, bottom, and leading in Android's FontMetrics

Tags: android, fontmetrics

This seems like a basic question, but I couldn't find a similar one on SO. While reading the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.FontMetrics.html), I was having trouble grasping the concepts. I want to understand what the difference is between `top` and `ascent` and also `bottom` and `descent`. And where exactly is the baseline? Do you have a diagram to help me visualize it?

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Let's first review what the [documentation says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.FontMetrics.html):

- **Top** - The maximum distance above the baseline for the tallest glyph in the font at a given text size.
- **Ascent** - The recommended distance above the baseline for singled spaced text.
- **Descent** - The recommended distance below the baseline for singled spaced text.
- **Bottom** - The maximum distance below the baseline for the lowest glyph in the font at a given text size.
- **Leading** - The recommended additional space to add between lines of text.

Note that the **Baseline** is what the first four are measured from. It is **line** which forms the **base** that the text sits on, even though some characters (like g, y, j, etc.) might have parts that go below the line. It is comparable to the lines you write on in a lined notebook.

Here is a picture to help visualize these things:

[image: FontMetrics showing top, ascent, baseline, decent, bottom, and leading]

Remember that when drawing on a canvas in Java and Android, going down is an *increase* in y and going up is a *decrease* in y. That means that FontMetrics' `top` and `ascent` are negative numbers since they are measured from the baseline (while descent and bottom are positive numbers). Thus, to get the distance from `top` to `bottom` you would need to do (`bottom` - `top`).

The **leading** is the distance between the bottom of one line and the top of the next line. In the picture above, it is the space between the orange of Line 1 and the purple of Line 2. As @MajorTom [noted below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37754766/3681880), in typography the term is more properly defined as "the distance between the baselines of successive lines of type."[*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading) However, Android seems to use the term in the more historical sense. The word (pronounced "ledding") comes from the lead strip that the old typesetters used to put between lines of type. It was basically just a way to adjust the line spacing. In Android I've never actually seen the leading be anything other than `0` and I haven't seen it used for anything in the source code. (Correct me if you know where it is used to calculate anything.) You can change the line spacing in a `TextView` with [`setLineSpacing`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLineSpacing%28float,%20float%29) in code or [`android:lineSpacingExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineSpacingExtra) and [`android:lineSpacingMultiplier`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineSpacingMultiplier) in xml. [These methods](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setLineSpacing%28float%2Cfloat%29), however, do not make use of or modify the leading.

Check out these links for more information:

- [Precise Android Text Drawing](http://www.slideshare.net/rtc1/intro-todrawingtextandroid)
- [Font Metrics in Java (and Android)](http://evendanan.net/2011/12/Font-Metrics-in-Java-OR-How-the-hell-Should-I-Position-This-Font/)
- [Layout documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html)
- [Java: FontMetrics ascent incorrect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202225/java-fontmetrics-ascent-incorrect)
- [FontMetrics not correct when run on android device. Simulator fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259015/fontmetrics-not-correct-when-run-on-android-device-simulator-fine)
- [Java Font Metrics](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/books/extracts/javanotesv3/c7/s1.html) (Java doesn't seem to use `top` and `bottom`)

## Explore more

In order to explore Font Metrics more, I made a simple project.

[image]

Rather than listing all the code here. I [added the project to GitHub](https://github.com/suragch/AndroidFontMetrics). You can either clone the project, or copy the following files into a new project.

- [*FontMetricsView.java*](https://github.com/suragch/AndroidFontMetrics/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/studymongolian/fontmetrics/FontMetricsView.java) (a custom view)
- [*MainActivity.java*](https://github.com/suragch/AndroidFontMetrics/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/studymongolian/fontmetrics/MainActivity.java)
- [*activity_main.xml*](https://github.com/suragch/AndroidFontMetrics/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml)

#### Do letters ever go above `top` or below `bottom`?

Not usually, but they could. Top and bottom, as I understand them, are set by the font (hence "FontMetrics"), so a font maker could make a glyph go higher than whatever they say the top is (or lower than the bottom). Also, with [combining diacritical marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) in Unicode it can very easily happen. Here is a rather extreme example (taken from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99586/284743)): M̵̳̙͔̟̱͕̓̀̄̉̅ͧ̋͊͌͑́͌ͪ̒̿̀̚a͔̟̝͔ͥ̈́̏ͮͯ̇͆̊̒ͦͦ͘͢͜y̵̴̢͕̝̩̱͈͕̼̣͕̟̌͗̾ͤ̎͌̄ͣͨ͊ͬb̡̯̰̪̜͙̟̝̠͚̜̥̙̤̃ͨ̋̒̒̊ͧͤ͐̓͋̌̾̇̔̈́̀́͡͠e̵ͯͪ̿̿̂̄ͫ̃҉͏͎̣̹̱̜͉̦̞̪̘̠̝̝͍̼̜̖̥̭͟ ̣̞͙͚̝̰̞̹̗̲̣͙͍͍̀̓͊̂̋ͣ̏̑̍̊͌ͩ͐̎̀ͣͣ̚͟ͅh̛͋̏̍̆ͤ͛͐ͨ̌̋ͤ̎̂ͨ̂̓̑̚̕͟͏̻̣͖̖͚͚͓̲̼̪ȁ̔̅̿͐̑͡͏̝͓̮͚̘̦̰͚͎͔͉͚̮̠̕͜ͅṱ̱̼̖̓̂ͭ̏̅͂ͥ͌ͯ͌͠sͪ̓ͪ̄̌̓ͧ͋͐ͬ̅̑҉̨̪̬͎͍̥̬?̡̮̳͙͓͔̹̘̹͓̘̻̦̣͎̫̐ͤ̐͛́͝ ̧̦̼̘͕̪̠̙͖̦̯̦̘͉͈͕͔̘̻̲͑ͨ̊̈́̐ͫ͐̌ͯ̀͘͝Ḩ̷̸̸̹͉̩̜̹̞ͯ̃̃ͧͬͨ̌̀̾̐̈̇ͧ͛̃͐̀ͦ͞A̴̦̗̬̠͙̭͉̟̺͇̭̰͔͕̯̅̃͋ͪ̈́̉̓̌ͯ̈́͆̋̀ͤ̇̂̿̈́̂͡͡Ṱ̲͎͉̣̳̺̱̜̦̬͕̣͉͇͊̌ͥ͐͒̈́̓́ͥ́́̋͂̅ͬ̆͗ͥ̕͢͡S̍ͧ͗̒͗̂̈ͬ͊̚̚͢͏̗̣̳ͅ!̶̨̡͇͚̙͚̭̱̣̲̳̤̞̫̗̣̦̮̖̞͒͆̿̄͑̃̎͡

Plugging that string into Android we get this:

[image]

The diacritical marks go above the `top` and below the `bottom`. It is interesting to note that the total width and height are correctly measured by the text bounds, though.

Anyway, for all practical purposes in your programming, you can just assume that the max and min for glyph letters are `top` and `bottom`. And usually they will stay within `ascent` and `descent`. If for whatever reason you need to know for sure if the letters go beyond `top` or `bottom` you can use [`TextPaint.getTextBounds`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42091739/3681880).

Comment: Nice! Do you know in what units are the ascent, descent etc measured in? Are they in pixels? They are float values but not sure how they correspond to the screen. Got them checked in photoshop to see if it is pixels and there is a slight difference of a few units; pixels being smaller.

Comment: @VikramGupta. The units are pixels. I'm not sure what caused the difference with your photoshop image check.

Comment: Thanks for the useful explanation and the app. But, can u further explain, what is exactly `Top`? Will there be any letter tall enough to touch the `Top` line? For instance, "M", "l" seems to be the tallest letter. None of them touching `Top`.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng, see the update at the end of my answer.

Comment: @Suragch Thanks for the info. I use your app to understand more. I expect "Ascent" line will just touch the top of the font nicely as in your screenshot. However, from the latest http://i.imgur.com/aRxgjvu.png , it is not touching the tallest character "M". Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng, That is what I expected at first, too. But remember that "M" is not necessarily the tallest glyph in a font. Or even if it is the tallest letter in a particular font, the font makers may be leaving room for other characters which could be taller. Don't forget emoji. I just tested the  emoji and it touched both the ascent and decent lines. So usually Latin letters never actually touch the ascent line, which makes the picture in my answer a little deceptive.

Answer (score 5):

Leading is NOT space between lines in typography. Apparently this is something Android code does not take into account. We've been struggling with this ourselves. The proper definition of leading ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading)):

> In typography, leading /ˈlɛdɪŋ/ refers to the distance between the
>   baselines of successive lines of type. The term originated in the days
>   of hand-typesetting, when thin strips of lead were inserted into the
>   forms to increase the vertical distance between lines of type.

From what I can tell, Android does not have a way to specify this.

Comment: +1 for helping me understand leading better. As far changing the leading goes, you can use TextView's `setLineSpacing` in code or `android:lineSpacingExtra` and `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` in xml.

Comment: Thanks - yes we were told to use `android:lineSpacingExtra` which would put a measurement between the actual space *between* the lines. It's not leading, but it seems like the only way to manage the spacing. It's a problem because there's no such measurement in typography, and there's no such way to specify that measure in Sketch or Zepelin (the tools we use). Plus it doesn't match the leading.

Comment: If typographical leading is the distance between baselines, it seems like it should be easy to calculate.

Comment: That's what I thought. Is there a way to do it programmatically? I was hoping with the methods Android provides that there might be a way to do it. The devs we work with don't seem to know.

Comment: It has been a while since I have worked with this, but if I were going to take it up again I would start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654321/measuring-text-height-to-be-drawn-on-canvas-android) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043427/how-to-get-ascender-descender-and-x-height-for-a-given-font) and experiment with different text and fonts. Even if it isn't straight forward, I can't believe that there isn't a way to calculate what you need.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276853/how-to-measure-textview-height-based-on-device-width-and-font-size) as well.

Comment: That is indeed the definition from typography, but in CSS at least line-gaps (due to leading) are divided into the top *and* bottom parts of a line, and thus line height is measured from between line boxes. This is a better way that classical typography, which was not possible to do in the days of yore.