# Set ascent, descent, baseline of text in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I need two TextViews to have same baseline, ascent, bottom, descent values. Is it possible to change the FontMetrics of TextView after text has been drawn?

Comment: did you check `TextView` docs? is there anything related to "size" ?

Comment: @pskink I did check. There wasn't any public api related to that. However getPaint() provided the fontmetrics values. I was wondering if we could change it inside the paint object.

Comment: nothing related to size in `TextView` api?

Comment: There are apis related to textSize. But there is no api that could allow us to change Fontmetrics. For instance,  if i want to draw text with 5 pixels above baseline, i cannot achieve it with textSize apis.

Comment: so use `android.text.Spannable` and "spans" concept for such things

Answer (score 2):

It is so late, but I also confronted with this issue, and I solve with some tricks. (`just modify baseline`, not ascent, descent or something)

---

1. note that `fontMetrics' values`(ascent, descent, bottom, top) are depend on `textSize`.

   so we must use `fontMetrics' values` after `view is drawn`. (if it is autoSizing or something)

   > to do something after view drawn, using [Sa Qada's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42950862/7354469)
2. `baseline is always 0.` descent, ascent, top, bottom is relative values.

   > refer this [Suragch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27631737/7354469).
3. change fontMetrics' values does not affect to UI.

   to set custom baseline(text position of textview), just use padding.
   below code is align to baseline with two TextView.

   ```
   // this is kotlin code, but I'm sure you can understand
   // align textview2 to textview1's baseline

   val tv1Baseline = tv1.paddingBottom + tv1.paint.fontMetrics.bottom
   val tv2Baseline = tv2.paddingBottom + tv2.paint.fontMetrics.bottom
   val newPaddingOffset = tv1Baseline - tv2Baseline

   tv2.setPadding(tv2.paddingLeft, tv2.paddingTop, tv2.paddingRight,
                  tv2.paddingBottom + newPaddingOffset)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for answering, much appreciated. I will try this out.

Comment: @Siva but this may not really good idea. because you must consider text's alignment case by case.

Comment: Does this code actually aligns bottoms, not baselines?

Comment: @sandrstar As I know, baselines are always 0. so I just add bottom padding to align two textviews. So it aligns bottoms as you said.

Comment: Looks like it's not, I've just checked and at least in my case (code in my answer) return value from getBaseline() is different from 0, since it's 'Return the offset of the widget's text baseline from the widget's top boundary' (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView)

Comment: @sandrstar Thanks for your explanation. I think you're right. My second section(baseline always 0) is just for fontMetrics(textPaint), not textview. by the way, can I ask 1 question? Is your code also work at when layout does not support baseline alignment?

Comment: I think so. I'm using it in my custom layout in order to align two textviews baselines. It does use TextView baseline calculations, but not align_baseline parameter. Obviously, if layout does support baseline alignment, you don't need to use such tricks as in my (or initially yours) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's solution to align baselines (note the difference from bottom in [Suragch answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27631737/657487) and definition of return value of [TextView.getBaseline()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#getBaseline())) which alignes tv2 baseline to tv1s':

```
private void alignWeatherTextBaseline(View tv1, View tv2) {
    int tv1Baseline = tv1.getTop() + tv1.getBaseline();
    int tv2Baseline = tv2.getTop() + tv2.getBaseline();
    int newPaddingOffset = tv1Baseline - tv2Baseline;

    if (newPaddingOffset != 0) {
        tv2.setPadding(tv2.getPaddingLeft(),
                tv2.getPaddingTop(), tv2.getPaddingRight(),
                tv2.getPaddingBottom() - newPaddingOffset);
    }
}
```

Be aware of the following:

- if multiline text is possible, you need to write proper `getLastLineBaseline()` and use it instead of standard `getBaseline()`
- you can get invalid value (0 or -1) from getBaseline() if a view hasn't been layout yet