# What is the difference between Paint and TextPaint in Android?

Tags: android, canvas, text, paint

What is the difference between `Paint` and `TextPaint`? Can only `TextPaint` draw text to a canvas?

I've been researching how to draw text on a canvas recently, which leads me to `TextPaint`. However, while reading [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/TextPaint.java) I was surprised to learn that there isn't much at all to `TextPaint`. In fact you don't actually need it to draw text on a canvas. So I am adding this Q&A to make this more clear.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`TextPaint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html) is a subclass of [`Paint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html). However, contrary to what you might guess from these names, the heavy work of drawing the text on the canvas is done by `Paint`. Thus, this

```
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
textPaint.setTextSize(50);
canvas.drawText("some text", 10, 100, textPaint);
```

and this

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setTextSize(50);
canvas.drawText("some text", 10, 100, paint);
```

actually do the same thing. `TextPaint` is just a light wrapper around `Paint` and gives Android some [extra data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html#lfields) to work with when drawing and measuring text. You can see this in action if you read the [`TextLine` class source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/TextLine.java) (this class draws a line of text). This is apparently why you have to pass in a `TextPaint` and not a `Paint` object when creating something like a [`StaticLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html).

**TextPaint fields**

The documentation is pretty sparse on what the "extra data" is here is a little fuller explanation. *(**Disclamer**: By changing these values in a `TextPaint`, I couldn't actually affect any changes to how the text was drawn in my tests. So take this section with a grain of salt.)*

- [`baselineShift`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html#baselineShift) - The baseline is the line at the base of the text. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27631737/3681880) for an image. Changing `baselineShift` causes the baseline to move up or down so it affects how high the text is drawn on a line.
- [`bgColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html#bgColor) - This is the background color behind the text.
- [`density`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html#density) - I assume this is the screen density but I couldn't find it being used in any source code.
- [`drawableState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html#drawableState) - I couldn't find much in the source code except a [`PFLAG_DRAWABLE_STATE_DIRTY`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.0PFLAG_DRAWABLE_STATE_DIRTY) flag, which makes me think this is used to let objects know when they need to be redrawn.
- [`linkColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html#linkColor) - I can only assume this means what it says, the text color of a link. However, I couldn't find this being used in any source code.

**Notes**

- [`TextPaint` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/TextPaint.java)
- [`Paint` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/donut-release/tools/layoutlib/bridge/src/android/graphics/Paint.java)
- Please leave a note or update this answer if you have any more information.

Comment: Concerning `linkColor`, I noticed that it is being used by [ClickableSpan](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.java) while investigating the option for individual styled / coloured spans in a `Spannable`.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through the source code slightly, I found the public parameters like `baselineShift` is actually **NOT** applied to the canvas when you invoke `drawText` using the textPaint as parameter but an extra data the `TextPaint` save for you to retrieve to manually apply to the drawing action.

For example, I want (0, 0) to be the center position of the text I draw, and that's how I usually did.

**Example**

```kotlin
private val mTextPaint = TextPaint().apply {
    color = Colors.BLACK
    textSize = 14.sp
    isAntiAlias = true
    baselineShift = (textSize / 2 - descent()).toInt()
    textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
}
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    canvas.drawText("Hello World", 0f, mTextPaint.baselineShift.toFloat(), mTextPaint)
}
```

**Note:** `sp` is an extension property in kotlin, which works like the function `sp2px(Number sp)`
And the `(textSize / 2 - descent()).toInt()` may not be the most accurate approach to center the text verically, please leave a comment if you have any better approach.