# Arrow symbol is positioned too low

Tags: android, textview

Does anyone know for what reason arrow is not in the middle of TextView?

Compare how it looks in Android:[image] with how it looks in a browser [image]

The code adding it looks like this:

```
for (Ticket ticket : tickets) {
            TextView tvDestination = new TextView(ctx);
            tvDestination.setTextAppearance(ctx, R.style.purchase_row_title);
            tvDestination.setText(ticket.getDepartureStationName() + getDirection(ticket.getTicketType()) + ticket.getArrivalStationName() + " / " + ticket.getDepartureDate());
            tvDestination.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon_ticket, 0, 0, 0);
            tvDestination.setCompoundDrawablePadding(24);
            tvDestination.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
            tvDestination.setMaxLines(1);
            h.rlDestinations.addView(tvDestination, 0);
        }
```

Style is:

```
<style name="purchase_row_title">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:drawableStart">@drawable/icon_ticket</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#242528</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Show layout please

Comment: It is in the middle. But padding above big text and below small text are not same, that's why it looks like it is not in middle. Try to put same padding and then check it.

Answer (score -1):

Actually that arrow is in the middle. You should [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27631737/7134908) post and take a understanding about **Ascent** and **Descent**  of the `TextView`

Comment: use android:includeFontPadding="false" with text to remove extra space

Comment: or android:layout_marginTop="-5dp" set padding according to your UI

Comment: Neither of it helped unfortunately. But still, why downvote?