# Some elements displayed differently in different browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser

I encountered the following problem when creating the icon:

https://jsfiddle.net/522r16jk/

It is displayed differently in different browsers.
HTML

```
<span class="add-btn">+</span>
<span class="delete-btn">+</span>
```

SASS

```
  span{
    display: flex;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 2px solid;
    font-size: 21px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    &.add-btn{
      color:$main-color;
      border-color: $main-color;
      margin-right: 10px;
      &:hover{
        color: $background-color;
        background-color: $main-color;
      }
    }
    &.delete-btn{
      color:#df4837;
      border-color: #df4837;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      &:hover{
        color: $background-color;
        background-color: #df4837;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: welcome maxim! While you did not actually ask a question, you probably mean to ask why this happens, or how to stop this from happening? Your question will probably me better received if you actually ask your question. Even better if you add you attempts to fix it, and if you googled for differences between those browsers. Sadly, I don't know the answer, just trying to help you get one :)

Comment: I think it's obvious that I want to fix this problem.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't completely clear enough, although at least I tried to be polite. Let me refrase it: I did not say you were not clear as I even commented that I understood the question. What I did say is that your question will probable be better received if you type it out. This is not me criticing you, this is me trying to help you get a better result here. If you don't want that (meta-)help, then fine. As your question does not actually have a question in it and shows no research effort, I suspect it won't do well. But maybe you will get an answer? Lets hope so.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't render as the posted image does, and because of that it is very difficult to understand what you actually ask so I voted to close this as such. If you want this post to stay opened you have to make it much clearer, and with a _working_ code sample that actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/522r16jk/ - i try to add this on jsfiddle

Comment: Looks the same to me in both FF and Chrome

Comment: @MaximZagumennyy While the fiddle does produce different results in different browsers, the differences are not the same as what your screenshots show.

Comment: @LGSon On my machine at least, the rotated + in the second icon is not centered in the circle in Firefox.

Comment: Centering font character with CSS will never be pixel prefect and render the exact same way in different browsers...and I personally can't see that either browser center it differently. Are we talking about 1px difference?

Comment: Chrome - http://prntscr.com/g7wbko
FF - http://prntscr.com/g7wbq4

Each time it is displayed in different ways

Comment: @MrLister On mine too...1px off, and as the space and the "x"'s pixel size is uneven, it has to be.

Comment: @MaximZagumennyy For us to be able to help, you need to post a code that reproduce the behavior you describe, or else we won't be able to help. And as I commented before, you won't be able to do this pixel perfect using font characters. Use pseudo elements or an image for the cross and you can make it pixel perfect.

Comment: @LGSon I did not find a better solution than throw you a link to the whole page template - http://midliru.it-issolution.com/create_event.html

The problem is seen specifically in the phone field. - http://prntscr.com/g7ypfi

If you will be have any problem to find the phone field, you can add me to skype - dks19901

I do not want to use images because of the hover effect.

Comment: Are you talking about that the left circle with the plus sign is slightly to the left compared to the _phone_ icon above it?

Comment: @LGSon I say that in different browsers the plus and the cross look different. Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Simply put, there is no general fix as font metrics are dealt with slightly different based on which browser and OS it runs on. This post might clear things out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631736/meaning-of-top-ascent-baseline-descent-bottom-and-leading-in-androids-font

Comment: @LGSon Solved the question thanks to svg