# How to get text BaseLine from Paint

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to draw a text at the centre of canvas, Since canvas starts drawing text at BaseLine, I am not able to Place it at centre. If i can get the baseLine, then i can calculate the centre.

I have tried with `paint.getFontMetrics()` this gives ascent and descent but not baseLine.

Comment: [This answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631736/meaning-of-top-ascent-baseline-descent-bottom-and-leading-in-androids-font) Please check it

Comment: Yea I did in the same way. And it worked, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the calculations of `paint.getFontMetrics()` will happen with respect to baseLine. So if i just subtract `(getMeasuredHeight() / 2f) - (fontMetrics.ascent / 2f)` it will draw from center

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this code

```
private void drawCenter(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, String text) {
    canvas.getClipBounds(r);
    int cHeight = r.height();
    int cWidth = r.width();
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), r);
    float x = cWidth / 2f - r.width() / 2f - r.left;
    float y = cHeight / 2f + r.height() / 2f - r.bottom;
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
}
```