# Align two texts by font's ascent instead of baseline in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I know how to align text in Jetpack Compose to the baseline.

But now I would need to align two differently sized texts that follow each other in a `Row` by the [ascent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27631737/1211542) of the larger of these two fonts. I would like to think of this as aligning two texts "by the top baseline" if that makes sense.  `Modifier.align(Alignment.Top)` does not work as it will not align by the ascent but by the layout's top and then the texts are not aligned correctly at the top.

I have tried to look how to do this, but apparently there's no ready made function or modifier for this? I didn't even find a way to access Text's ascent property etc in Compose. So not sure how this would be possible?

Thanks for any hints! :)

**Edit**: This is what it looks when `Alignment.Top` is used. But I would like the two texts to align at the top.

[image]

Comment: I created a bug about this missing feature to Google. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/212634248

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All information about text layout can be retrieved with `onTextLayout` `Text` argument. In this case you need a line size, which can be retrieved with `getLineBottom`, and an actual font size, which can be found in `layoutInput.style.fontSize`.

I agree that it'd be easier if you could use some simple way to do that, so I've starred your [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/212634248), but for now here's how you can calculate it:

```kotlin
onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
    val ascent = textLayoutResult.getLineBottom(0) - textLayoutResult.layoutInput.run {
        with(density) {
            style.fontSize.toPx()
        }
    }
},
```

Full example of aligning two texts:

```kotlin
val ascents = remember { mutableStateMapOf<Int, Float>() }
val texts = remember {
    listOf(
        "Big text" to 80.sp,
        "Small text" to 20.sp,
    )
}
Row(
    Modifier
        .drawBehind {
            ascents.maxOfOrNull { it.value }?.let {
                drawLine(Color.Red, Offset(0f, it), Offset(size.width, it))
            }
        }
) {
    texts.forEachIndexed { i, info ->
        Text(
            info.first,
            fontSize = info.second,
            onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
                ascents[i] = textLayoutResult.getLineBottom(0) - textLayoutResult.layoutInput.run {
                    with(density) {
                        style.fontSize.toPx()
                    }
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .alpha(if (ascents.count() == texts.count()) 1f else 0f)
                .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                    val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
                    val maxAscent = ascents.maxOfOrNull { it.value } ?: 0f
                    val ascent = ascents[i] ?: 0f
                    val yOffset = if (maxAscent == ascent) 0 else (maxAscent - ascent).toInt()
                    layout(placeable.width, placeable.height - yOffset) {
                        placeable.place(0, yOffset)
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Philip for the answer! I really appreciate you taking the time and making a working sample out of this! This indeed seems to work fine - I will adopt your solution :) This is a working solution - which is nice - but hopefully the Jetpack Compose team can provide this out of the box. And I didn't know how to get the ascent, so thanks for that also!

Comment: @Pylyp Hi sir! Hope all going well!! I read several answers from you in SO about this topic (onTextLayout / paddingFromBaseLine etc.) I was wondering if there is any stuff can you please share? I don't think I saw them from Android developer site. Thank you!

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO. I don't have, I learn everything by inspecting the API. You can check some other answers of mine using [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a3585796%20code%3a%22onTextLayout%22)

Comment: @PylypDukhov Awesome!! Thank you! Have a nice day (and stay safe!!)!!!

Comment: Sorry but your code doesn't work for me 
Maybe because of the library updates

Comment: Update: The issue is in my custom font. 
Each font has their own baselines. That's why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

in addition to [one of the previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70602342/5629995)
ascent and descent

[image]

```
Text(
    modifier = modifier,
    text = text,
    onTextLayout = { result ->
        val layoutInput = result.layoutInput
        val fontSize = with(layoutInput.density) { layoutInput.style.fontSize.toPx() }
        val lineHeight = with(layoutInput.density) { layoutInput.style.lineHeight.toPx() }
        var baseline = result.firstBaseline
        (0 until result.lineCount).forEach { index ->
            val top = result.getLineTop(index)
            val bottom = result.getLineBottom(index)
            val ascent = bottom - fontSize
            val descent = bottom - (baseline - fontSize - top)
            baseline += lineHeight
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be you can adjust y-axis offset modifier according to your need.

```
Text(text = "Second", modifier = Modifier.offset(x = 0.dp, y = 5.dp))
```

you can have negative value for offset as well if you like to up your first text according to your need.

Comment: Yes, that would be one option. But feels hackish to me and the value would depend on the font used. 

This would be the last resort and workaround that I would implement if there is no proper solution for this in Compose. Which to be honest would be a surprise if it does not exist. And I would probably file a bug for it.

Comment: If your first Text component will be another size then offset won't be correct

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use ConstraintLayout. You can simply constrain the tops of the two texts https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/constraintlayout