# Android Jetpack Compose Trying to Align a Text inside a Box

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I created a `Box` containing an `Image` and `Text`. With `Box` `contentAlignment` set to `TopStart`, the `Text` is not aligning properly with the `Image`. Horizontally, things look ok, but there is unexpected vertical padding (even after setting it 0).

Similarly, `BottomStart` alignment sets the `Text` a few pixels higher than the `Image`.

```
Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart,) {
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background), contentDescription = "",
        modifier = Modifier.size(125.dp),
        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground)
    )

    Text(text = "4",
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
        fontSize = 44.sp,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}
```

[image: Box-Preview]

Comment: See how [text drawing works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631736/meaning-of-top-ascent-baseline-descent-bottom-and-leading-in-androids-font)

Answer (score 23):

You can check according to here:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
.
.
   Box(modifier = Modifier.size(height = 90.dp, width = 290.dp)) {
    Text("TopStart", Modifier.align(Alignment.TopStart))
    Text("TopCenter", Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter))
    Text("TopEnd", Modifier.align(Alignment.TopEnd))

    Text("CenterStart", Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart))
    Text("Center", Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
    Text(text = "CenterEnd", Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd))

    Text("BottomStart", Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart))
    Text("BottomCenter", Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter))
    Text("BottomEnd", Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd))
   }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

You need to use the `.align()` modifier on your `Text` inside the `Box` to center/position it. e.g. `Text(..., modifier = Modifier.align(Center), ..)`.

Alternatively, you can make your text fill up the entire `Box` (by adding `.fillMaxSize()` to it) and the use the `textAlign` property.

Comment: I will try your suggestion when I can. Thanks

Comment: I tried using both methods you mentioned but none worked. The modifier align is same as text Align property. And i can't use fillmaxsize because it would fill the whole screen not the whole box

Comment: Have you added the modifier to the `Text`?

Also you can try `contentAlignment = Alignment.Center`. If that doesn't fix it, its your `Box` is the exact size as your text (so they match up, regardless of the alignment).

Comment: if i add the modifier android studio marks Tet as error . i tried with modifier alone it was same result. what baffles me the most id in the picture the horiizontal borders fot the number 4 are exact sizze with no extra space but the vertical borderss arehigher than the size of number 4

Comment: even in content aligment center for the box the number 4 is centered but it is off center approx x +5dp y +5dp . so its off center leaning down and right a little . thats what is driving me insane

Comment: If `.align` isn't working, make sure you don't have `propagateMinConstraints` turned on, which can make your content take up more room than expected, messing up the alignment.

Answer (score 3):

We can set the `Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight()` for the box to solve this problem.

```
    Box(modifier =
    Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight()
        ,contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Text(text = "Tap")
    }
```

Comment: Do you know why your answer with `contentAlignment = Alignment.Center` works, but the other one where children like `Text` use `Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)` does nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Before aligning the content inside the box, the box size should be defined.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
){
    Text(
        text = "Center"
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems i need to use BasicTextField to remove the upper and lower extra padding, it is something related to Material Desgin Layout decoration.

i just used modifier offset to fix my issue by aligning it correctly