# compose align right or left (no start or end)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

im creating a view using jetpack-compose.
i have a view and i want it to be align to **right** of the Box.
i **don't want to use end or start**.
how to do it?
i saw absoluteAlignment but its not working

```
modifier = Modifier.align(AbsoluteAlignment.Left)
```

one solution was:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
            // Add your app composable elements here
        }
```

and use start and end based on that.
but i want to know if there is any posibility to use RIGHT or LEFT directly.

Comment: Compose has (correctly) abstracted away left and right into start and end. Why do you want to break that feature?

Comment: can you put up full code of the composable?

Comment: Can you please let us know why you don't want to use `end or start` What's the problem with end or start that you are facing? Or are you trying to mean something else? 
You may check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/74647369/10599979 if you want to align your elements with box.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `horizontalArrangement` of the `Row()` composable

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Absolute.Right) {
        Text(text = "your Text Aligned right")
    }
```