# Jetpack Compose: how to place text on the right side of the row?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-jetpack-compose-row

I'm trying to place two texts inside a `Row`, one nailed to the left edge, the other to the right. Moreover, if the left text is too long, it should not overlap the right text, but should be wrapped on a new line. The problem is that both the right and left texts are optional. If, for example, there is no left text, I need the right text to be located on the line at the right edge.

Here's an example of what it should look like[image]

Here is my code:

```
   Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(top = 4.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                ) {
                    if (hasLeft()) {
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                            text = leftText,                            
                        )
                    }

                    if (hasRight()) {
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 4.dp),
                            text = rightText,                                
                        )
                    }
                }
```

As a result, when the no left text, the right text is located on the left side, but I need it to be on the right, how to fix this?

Please, help me.

Comment: Try add this line to your right text ```textAlign = TextAlign.Right``` it might work

Comment: you can use Box like this->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70608914/android-jetpack-compose-trying-to-align-a-text-inside-a-box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set fill property of Modifier.weight to false for the left Text and add a Spacer when left text is not available

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(top = 4.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
) {
    if (hasLeft) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false),
            text = leftText,
        )
    }else {
        Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
    }

    if (hasRight) {

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 4.dp),
            text = rightText
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are limiting yourself into thinking that in all cases it has to be `Row`.

```
when {
    hasLeft() && hasRight() -> YourOriginalRow()
    hasLeft() -> `Row/Box with only left text`()
    hasRight() -> `Box with only right text`()
}
```