# How to centre align text in Compose Row irrespective of another Image?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to centre align Text in a compose Row and put the image at the end of the Row with some right padding as well I tried using weight but the text is not in the centre due to the image.

```
 Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
        .shadow(8.dp)
        .background(Orange_Light, shape = shape)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(vertical = 20.dp)
            .weight(1f)
        ,
        text = "\uD83D\uDE4F\uD83C\uDFFBNamaste",
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )

    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(40.dp)
            .padding(end = 18.dp)
        ,
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_right_arrow),
        contentDescription = ""
    )
}
```

[image: Button]

Comment: image is your output or do you want it like that?

Comment: Create Box inside row with fillMaxWidth() and align text to top center and image to top end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`Box`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#Box(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)) Composable together with the [`align`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).align(androidx.compose.ui.Alignment)) Modifer. A `Box` stacks its children on the z-axis, so you can center the `Text` independently of the `Image`.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
        .shadow(8.dp)
        .background(Orange_Light, shape = shape)
        .fillMaxWidth()
) {

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(vertical = 20.dp)
            .align(Alignment.Center),
        text = "\uD83D\uDE4F\uD83C\uDFFBNamaste",
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )

    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(40.dp)
            .padding(end = 18.dp)
            .align(Alignment.CenterEnd),
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_right_arrow),
        contentDescription = ""
    )
}
```

Also have a look at [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74647369/8331157) that provides all available alignment Modifiers.

Be aware that with that approach, when the text is too long, it will be overlapped by the image. If you have to avoid that, I think there is no other way than setting the left padding of the text to the same width as the image, which in your case should be `48.dp`.