# Why is there extra spacing for some characters which cause QPainter::drawText to be cutoff?

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qfont, qfontmetrics

I'm trying to use `QPainter::drawText()` to render some Chinese characters. But in certain fonts, there is extra top spacing when drawing the text. Why is this happening to some characters only?

Tested on Qt version 6.6.3 & 5.15.2

Googled some info, but nothing really answers the question:

- [Meaning of top, ascent, baseline, descent, bottom, and leading in Android's FontMetrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631736/meaning-of-top-ascent-baseline-descent-bottom-and-leading-in-androids-font)
- [Qt Forum — Impossible to get true text hight with QFontMetrics/QFontMetricsF](https://forum.qt.io/topic/117903/impossible-to-get-true-text-hight-with-qfontmetrics-qfontmetricsf/8)
- [QTBUG-53271 — FontMetrics BoundingRect size is incorrect with chinese characters and any higher DPI text](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53271)

As you can see below: green box is with metric height, while red is with bounding height. Sure, the bounding height does bound the entire text, but there is extra top and bottom spacing.

[image]

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QFont>
#include <QFontMetrics>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    // Call base class implementation first
    QMainWindow::paintEvent(event);

    // Obtain the QPainter object
    QPainter paint(this);

    QFont font;
    font.fromString("Apple LiGothic");
    font.setPointSize(50);
    QFontMetrics metric(font);

    paint.setRenderHints(QPainter::TextAntialiasing | QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    paint.setFont(font);
    paint.setPen(Qt::white);
    const int align = Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop | Qt::TextWordWrap;

    QString text = "钳禾日当午";
    QRect bound = metric.boundingRect(text);
    bound = QRect(0, 0, bound.width(), bound.height());
    QRect metricBound(0, 0, bound.width(), metric.height());
    paint.translate(10, 100);
    paint.setPen(Qt::red);
    paint.drawRect(bound);
    paint.setPen(Qt::green);
    paint.drawRect(metricBound/*.adjusted(0,10,0,10)*/); // hack adjustment
    paint.setPen(Qt::white);
    paint.drawText(0, 0, bound.width(), bound.height(), align, text);

    text = "汗滴禾下土";
    bound = metric.boundingRect(text);
    bound = QRect(0, 0, bound.width(), bound.height());
    metricBound = QRect(0, 0, bound.width(), metric.height());
    paint.translate(0, 100);
    paint.setPen(Qt::red);
    paint.drawRect(bound);
    paint.setPen(Qt::green);
    paint.drawRect(metricBound);
    paint.setPen(Qt::white);
    paint.drawText(0, 0, bound.width(), bound.height(), align, text);
}
```

Comment: Try to use the proper [`boundingRect()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-2) function that *constrains* the text to a given rect, otherwise you'll be setting improper origin (and translated) coordinates based on wrong alignment, since you are always using `0, 0` as absolute origin.

Comment: Using the "proper" boundingRect that you mentioned still has the same issue... It returns different boundingRect for different characters.

Comment: Different how? The `boundingRect()` functions may return different rectangles, and, as said, you shall not use `0, 0` as an origin, but the actual rect returned from the function, otherwise you'll get misleading results from such testing. Can you please do further testing with the correct coordinate reference (and also help us identifying the text in code and images, even with a simple "1" and "2", as most of us cannot tell apart Chinese characters and both strings seem similar to uneducated eyes).