How to align text at top edge of canvas using StaticLayout?
I'm using the StaticLayout.Builder in Android, and have created a text that i want to be at the edge of the top of the canvas, however i can't seem to get rid of a margin that comes between top of canvas (y=0) and text.
I have tried simply setting y=0, and remove all kind of padding/margin i can find like:
val textPaint = TextPaint().apply { color = Color.RED; textSize = 50f; isAntiAlias = true
    val metrics = fontMetrics
    metrics.ascent = 0f
    metrics.descent = 0f
    metrics.top = 0f
}

And use "setIncludePad(false)" on the builder.
It seems that right, left and bottom don't have the padding/margin, its only on top.
I have also drawn a basic "rect" using x=0 and y=0 which aligns at all 4 edges, so the canvas should be correctly set and have its edges on correct places.
Does anyone know why there is a margin over the text when using StaticLayout and setting y=0, and how to get rid of it?

You probably don't wanna try to modify font metrics. It's a bit more straightforward to offset your y by the necessary difference. The question is, though, how exact do you want this? Does it need to adjust for strings of different heights – e.g., "Text" vs. "text" – or are you just looking to move the font's ascent to the top edge?

This answer has a nice illustration that explains why that's happening: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27631737. The StaticLayout is aligning the font's top to 0, so you're seeing the gap between the top and the actual top of your text.

Thanks! That helped me understand why some of the values are negative and some positive, its because its relative to baseline. I tried setting y to the value of "top - ascent" which helped a lot, however there is still a few pixels left as margin, but this is much better than what I had earlier, and its good to know it wont get a too big offset since we're using values from "top" and "ascent" :)

No problem! Btw, if you need an exact solution, you would use one of Paint's getTextBounds() methods to get the actual top to use in the offset calculation instead of the ascent. You have to instantiate your own Rect first and pass that in, then its top will be set to the text's actual top. Just FYI. Cheers!
